# Avoid redundant computation of new columns in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Here is the code:

```
  import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
  import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, SQLContext}
  import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
  import vu.co.kaiyin.Utils.withRDD
  Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
  Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("wordCount").setMaster("local[4]")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
  import sqlContext.implicits._

  case class PatientReadings(
                              val patientId: Int,
                              val heightCm: Int,
                              val weightKg: Int,
                              val age:Int,
                              val isSmoker:Boolean
                            )

  val readings = List(
    PatientReadings(1, 175, 72, 43, false),
    PatientReadings(2, 182, 78, 28, true),
    PatientReadings(3, 164, 61, 41, false),
    PatientReadings(4, 161, 62, 43, true)
  )
  val df = sc.parallelize(readings).toDF()
  df.show()

  val heightM = df("heightCm") / 100
  val bmi = df("weightKg") / (heightM * heightM)
```

`bmi` is displayed in the console like this:

```
    scala> bmi: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = (weightKg / ((heightCm / 100) * (heightCm / 100)))
```

Apparently the division was performed twice. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a UDF

```
val bmiFunc = udf((heightCm: Double, weightKg: Double) => {
  val heightM = heightCm / 100
  weightKg / (heightM * heightM)
})
val bmi = bmiFunc(df("heightCm"), df("weightKg"))
```

Or if you need `heightM` and `bmi` separately

```
val heightM = df("heightCm") / 100
val bmiFunc = udf((heightM: Double, weightKg: Double) => {
  weightKg / (heightM * heightM)
})
val bmi = bmiFunc(heightM, df("weightKg"))
```

Answer (score 1):

These are automatically generated column names and shouldn't affect actual execution but if you're concerned you can always replace multiplication with `pow` function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.pow 

$"weightKg" / pow($"heightCm" / 100, 2)
```